# Implied inverse forex pair bid/ask spread

Tags: fx

I just wanted to make sure this was correct:

If AUD/USD has bid ask of 0.71999/  0.72032, that implies there is another (theoretical) pair USD/AUD which has a bid ask of (1/aud_usd_ask) / (1/aud_usd_bid) .

The reason for the theoretical pair is that if my quote currency profits are in AUD, I only have the AUD/USD bid/ask to convert back into USD and I want to make sure I have the correct bid/ask spread for the inverse pair that I'm going to use.

Ie, if I have a profit of 1000 AUD, then to convert back into USD by purchasing USD / selling AUD, I would use 1000 AUD / (1/AUD_USD_BID)

and if I have a loss of 1000 AUD, then I'd need to buy the AUD back and sell my USD in my account.  For that I would use 1000 AUD / (1/AUD_USD_ASK)

Correct??  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, but in finance, you should avoid talking about the theoretical pair you are talking about as you will make it even more confusing.